Power source switch
I have a Ghost Control automatic gate opener that is powered by a 12v marine battery. My battery charging options are solar or using an AC transformer. I have both, but only 1 can be used at a time. I want something that all I have to do is flip a switch. Currently I have to uninstall the AC transformer and install the solar if I want to switch. I need something that both sets of wires go in and both sets of wires come out, but the toggle/switch lets me decide. Thanks

Steven Lindgren - Thanks for adding that diagram. I had not guessed that is what was meant from the text description, so the diagram was important. || Don't expect that someone will necessarily recommend a product (they might, but might not) since shopping recommendation requests are off-topic. || Now we can see what is being switched, it will be helpful if you can give the voltage & current ratings for the solar & AC transformer supplies, as that is relevant for the rating of the switch etc. || Have you any experience making small electric circuits e.g. soldering or crimping wires?

Is it really necessary to switch both legs of both circuits? It would seem to me that one leg on each side would be sufficient.

If the AC input goes through a bridge, then there is no common ground between either of the AC input pins and one of the DC input pins.

I know of switches that will make the connections you want electrically, but not at your power levels.  What will work. but is a bit of a kludge, is two DPST switches mounted next to each other with some kind of crossbar binding the two toggles together mechanically.  One of the switches is reversed with respect to the other such that:
When the toggles are up, the two AC wires are connected to the AC transformer inputs and the two Solar wires are disconnected.
When the toggles are down, the two Solar wires are connected to the DC inputs and the two AC wires are disconnected.
The same thing can be achieved with a 4PDT-center-off switch.  At your power level it might be expensive.  Schematic on request.
Please update the question with more complete voltage and current information for both sources.  What is the peak current in either power circuit?
Turns out - Digi-Key (and others) stock these things.  4PDT, either on-on, or on-off-on (center-off).  I'd go with the center-off because it guarantees that there won't be cross-conduction if two of the poles toggle a little faster.  I limited the results to current ratings of 5 A to 20 A.
Digi-Key 4PDT
